# Trouble with parameterizing a line integral where the scalar field contains absolute value

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having a bit of trouble with parameterizing the line integral (of a scalar field) $\int_C{(x+y)\lvert ds \rvert}$ where $C$ is $ \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = 1 $. Should I just use polar coordinates? This leads to some complicated derivatives, and I'm assuming there is a simpler solution, I just can't find it.

Comment: $C$ is made up of line segments from $y=\pm x\pm 1$

Comment: As David Peterson said, break the integral into four parts: (1) on y= 1- x with x from 1 to 0, (2) on y= 1+ x with x from -1 to 0, (3) on y= x+ 1 with x from -1 to 0, and (4) on y= x- 1 with x from 0 to 1.  On each of those, $|dx|= \sqrt{2} dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to parameterize the curve.

\begin{equation}
s(t)=\begin{cases}
(1-t)(1,0)+t(0,1)&\text{ for }0\le t<1\\
(2-t)(0,1)+(t-1)(-1,0)&\text{ for }1\le t<2\\
(3-t)(-1,0)+(t-2)(0,-1)&\text{ for }2\le t<3\\
(4-t)(0,-1)+(t-3)(1,0)&\text{ for }3\le t<4\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This gives

\begin{equation}
x(t)=\begin{cases}
1-t&\text{ for }0\le t<2\\
t-3&\text{ for }2\le t<4\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
y(t)=\begin{cases}
t&\text{ for }0\le t<1\\
2-t&\text{ for }1\le t<3\\
t-4&\text{ for }3\le t<4
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Notice that for this parameterization, $ds=\sqrt{2}\,dt$ on each subinterval.